# Centered website layout with varying sized columns and responsive?

Tags: css, web, center, centering

I'm looking to create a website (or at the very least a homepage) like Joules.com

I essentially want to create boxes side by side in varying sizes but want them to resize or move to a new line with the browser window resizing (responsive?). It's also necessary for them to be centered. I can get to the point where I have the divs side by side but they don't seem to be centered... Here's what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm kind of nooby in this department but wanting to learn!

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#Womens {
    height: auto
    width: 241px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#Mens {
    height: auto
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 241px;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
}
#Footwear {
    height: auto
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 241px;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
}
#Accessories {
    height: auto
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 241px;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body><center>
<div id="container">
  <div id="Womens">Womens</div>
  <div id="Mens">Mens</div>
  <div id="Footwear">Footwear</div>
  <div id="Accessories">Accessories</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First at all you don't need to use an ID for each element, since your CSS code is the same for everyone use a classname instead:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="column">Womens</div>
  <div class="column">Mens</div>
  <div class="column">Footwear</div>
  <div class="column">Accessories</div>
</div>
```

Then don't use `float` because you can't center those elements, use `inline-block`:

```
#container {
  font-size:0;
  text-align:Center;
}
.column {
  font-size:14px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Check this [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/21wnhvhL/)

Comment: The problem I have with this solution is that it works great on desktop but when I preview it on my iphone 5 the divs only separate to 2 per row instead of 1 per row. So I'm unable to see two of the divisions as they are off screen.

Comment: This works as you ask ... center columns and break as the width changes.... So this answer the question please limit your question to only one problem at time. Now To acomplish all your requirements you will need the use of media queries.

Comment: "or move to a new line with the browser window resizing" is also a part of my original question. Apologies for the confusion. What I need is for each div to land on a new line when it gets to a mobile width...

Comment: @Jamescwrk how this example doesn't work that way? .. this never offset the width of the window if it's more than 320px wich is the less value for mobile devices isntead break in new lines. Again if you need more exact beahvior use media queries

Comment: It doesn't put each box on a new line. At mobile resolution it displays two boxes next to each other, making one cut off. I would gladly use media queries if I knew how.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS could be much simpler by using a class ([Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) ;) ).

If you put `text-align: center;` on the container instead the container itself and its child contents will be centered. If you want you could then override the setting for the separate columns, or just for their content.

You've also used fixed pixel values for the column width, so they can't really be "responsive." You can use percentage values there as well, but that can have some screwy side effects. Note that 4 columns even with `auto` margins still need to be < 100% or else they wrap oddly. They also might collapse or overlap at smaller sizes. You can set a min-width on the container or the columns to help prevent this, along with a `margin-bottom` to keep them separate if they do wrap.

Also, if you just use percentage width and inline-block, the columns will be aligned at the bottom. Using `vertical-align: top;` fixes that. You said initially you wanted different heights, but if you didn't you could set a min- or max-height & put something like `overflow:scroll` on the content.

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center;
}
.box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 90px;
    padding: 1%;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #678;
    color: #fff;
}
.content {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="Womens" class="box">Womens
         <div class="content">This is some left-aligned women's content about/for women. View the Code Snippet in fullscreen!</div>
      </div>
      <div id="Mens" class="box">Mens
         <div class="content">This is some left-aligned men's content about/for men. If you resize the browser the columns will be responsive, but break after a certain point.</div>
      </div>
      <div id="Footwear" class="box">Footwear
         <div class="content">This is some left-aligned footwear content about/for feet. Feet are weird.</div>
      </div>
      <div id="Accessories" class="box">Accessories
         <div class="content">This is some left-aligned accessory content about stuff you men or women could potentially put on their feet, or whatever.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: I think they get far too small upon resize! Almost unreadable. What I'd like is for them to maintain their size but center position themselves beneath each other on smaller displays (Phones and tablets). I may not be explaining this as well as I could.

Comment: @Jamescwrk As I said above, you can keep the fixed pixel width, or set a minimum width property. In portrait mode on a phone set column `min-width:300px;` or so. They'll still expand a bit at larger screen sizes. Experiment with it & see what works. This was just an example to play around with. Also, you're welcome.

Comment: I'll have to try this somehow. I do appreciate your help, thank you.